# Form in a foreach in laravel blade

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a form in a @foreach loop in laravel blade but now upon load up, I can't submit the first form.

After inspecting, seen that the form tags for the first form aren't added to the file source code.

```
@foreach($images as $row)
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <form method="post" id="image_manipulator" action="{{ url('image/delete/'.$row->id) }}" class="delete_confirm">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="delete_filename" value="{{ $row->filename }}"> 
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-trash">DELETE</i>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

for the first image, i the form tags aren't there and hence I can't submit the first form.

Comment: double check if you have an opening <form> prior to your `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things will help you.

Add `type="submit"` to your button code instead of `type="button"`

Give independent names for each of your inputs to prevent collision, e.g.:

```
<input type="hidden" name="delete_filename-{{$someLoopVar}}" value="{{ $row->filename }}">
```

Comment: I don't think the above could affect anything, well am submitting the forms via jquery, and for all the rest except the first, this is working fine

Comment: Didn't realize you were submitting with Jquery.  Got different names for form elements, including the forms?

Comment: just nope just the id, which is similar each case in all loops,

Comment: Similar or same?  If the ids are the same, this is likely the issue - it is colliding and jquery isn't submitting the right form.  If same, try changing to add a loop var on the id for the inputs and the forms, as in my answer and see if that helps.